# Вывести значения цикла в переменную

Tags: php, циклы, foreach

подскажите как передать значения цикла в переменную, чтобы отправило на почту данные.
JS отправляет JSON, Далее идет обработчик:

```
$obj = $_POST['userAnswers'];
    $mass = '';
$mass = json_decode($obj);

foreach($mass as $key => $value){
 $mass .= '<b>' .$key. ' - </b>' . $value;
}

$email_to = "mail";

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html;' . "\r\n";
$headers .= '>'. "\r\n";

mail($email_to, 'Заказ', $mass, $headers);
```

Но приходит пустое письмо, как передать значения из цикла в переменную mail ($mass)??

Код JS: 
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sendmail.php",
    data: {
        userAnswers: JSON.stringify(r)
    });

Comment: У вас же в `$mass` массив, зачем с ним контантенируете? но перед этим проверьте что в `$obj`

Comment: в $obj приходит JSON с js (Вот код):       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sendmail.php",
        data: {
            userAnswers: JSON.stringify(r)
        }

Answer (score 1):

```
$obj = $_POST['userAnswers'];

$message = '';
foreach(json_decode($obj) as $key => $value){
 $message .= '<b>' .$key. ' - </b>' . $value . '<br/>';
}

$email_to = "mail";

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html;' . "\r\n";
$headers .= '>'. "\r\n";

mail($email_to, 'Заказ', $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Не сработало, пустое сообщение, вот что передается в JSON:       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sendmail.php",
        data: {
            userAnswers: JSON.stringify(r)
        }

Comment: @BloodKnight попробуйте вывести данные строкой: print_r(json_decode($obj)), посмотрите что приходит

Comment: Если в foreach то выводит массив, если за пределами пусто, может есть какие у вас еще идеи?